# How can I get awk to print without white space?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

When I run the following

```
awk -F\, '{print $2,":",$1}'
```

It prints

```
"First : Second"
```

How can I get

```
"First:Second"
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Omit the `,`s

```
awk -F\, '{print $2 ":" $1}'
```

Comment: this works because using the commas inserts OFS between the print arguments. You could also write `awk -F, -v OFS=: '{print $2, $1}'`

Comment: in some cases the ',' are needed with awk's arithmetic to yield correct OFMT value, or i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
awk -F\, '{print $2":"$1}'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 awk '{printf "%s:%s",$2,$1}'
```

You can also use printf instead of print  to get more control over printing things.